# Getting an error when going to a website to press a follow button

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I am trying to create a twitch follower bot, and have created simple code to go to the website and press the follow button, but it is not clicking the follow button.

```
import webbrowser

url = "https://twitch.tv/owlcrogs"
driver = webbrowser.open(url)


follow_button = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(get_page_element("follow_button"))
follow_button.click()
```

Comment: I will be creating a login function, right now I am just looking for it to press follow.

Answer (score 0):

Where is defined get_page_element("follow_button")? 
You must be sure It returns a valide xpath.

From Google Chrome you can inspect xpath with right click over the target element and select inspect. Then the developers tools are deployed. Over the selected item in the developers tools do [ right click >> copy >> copy Xpath ]

E.g.
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_element"]/div[2]/a/span').click()

If if doesn't something is wrong with get_page_element. What is the type of error returned?

I have just checked the webPage and maybe you must put 'follow-button' instead of 'follow_button' with an hyphen instead of an underscore. However, I hope get_page_element search by data-a-target attribute, xD.

Here is a example to do that:

```
def find_element_by_attribute(wrapper, attribute, selection=None, xpath = None):
        if selection is not None:
            element = list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute(attribute) is not None and \
                                            x.get_attribute(attribute).find(selection) != -1,\
                                            wrapper.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*' if xpath is None else xpath)))
        else:
            element = list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute(attribute) is not None,\
                                            wrapper.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*' if xpath is None else xpath)))

        return None if len(element) is 0 else element[0]
```

- wrapper : Page elements where search the target element (e.g. a div with li tags).
- attribute : Attribute used to select the target element.
- selecction : String with text which is in target attribute.
- xpath : Could be used to search in a subwrapper element.

You could save this code un a module e.g. auxiliars.py
So your code after defining this function should be something like this:

```
import webbrowser
from auxiliars import find_element_by_attribute

url = "https://twitch.tv/owlcrogs"
driver = webbrowser.open(url)

follow_button = find_element_by_attribute(driver, 'data-a-target', selection='follow-button')
follow_button.click()
```

Comment: __find_element_by_attribute(follow-button)

Comment: This is a working example which replace your line: driver.find_element_by_xpath(get_page_element("follow_button")). I edit the answer with the usage example in your code...